# Where to put django files on server?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a question. I work with one guy who is developing in Php, I am developing in Django right know. This is my first time doing something for other people and he firstly asked me to put my application to Apache Web server document root(I think he didn't know that much about Django, and he did everything this way), so I did it, because I didn't know that much about Apache and servers. But right know I am scared because I have all the python files in document root and I realized that this Web server document root `\www\myproject` might be accessible to other people. How should I change it, where should I put it, what is the best practice? I am deploying with `mod_wsgi` and `Apache 2.4`. In the documentation it says, that I shouldn't put code in Web server document root too, but if I put it somewhere else can I access it the same way, like I used to when it was on the Web server document root? Will I have to do something other than changing paths in Apache config?

Comment: You could potentially keep the files there and change the permissions to the directory so that only a limited group can access that directory. The problem is that, traditionally, files in that area are open to the world, meaning that the world could access and possibly execute. I would recommend moving, but if not possible, look into changing the permissions.

Comment: I stronly suggest you install Apache on your own development box and learn to configure it - you might teach quickly be able to teach some things to your php friend, like properly using virtualhosts instead of cramming everything and the kitchen sink under apache's document root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the Django project anywhere on the machine except for the apache document root, for security reasons as you have pointed out.
You can then configure apache to pint to the location of your wsgi.py which can live in the Django project if you wish:

`WSGIScriptAlias / <path to the wsgi.py>`

I'm not aware of a standard place to put the Django project root directory, I guess it depends on the OS and the distribution.

Comment: Nothing OS or distribution specific here. You can put your dango project anywhere as long as the front server process (apache or else) has permissions on this path.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to hear. This is how I thought it should be, but i wasn't sure because the Php guy said that i only need to move some files.